# Python, read how many lines there are, then take of one file every line and substract them with the number in the other file

Tags: python

So I have something like that:

```
global ausgebenlines
global verkauftlines
global first_line_ausgegeben
global first_line_ausgegeben

Gewinn = []
print('Wie viel noch da ist wird ausgerechnet...')
while True:
    def test():
        with open('Text1.txt') as f:
            ausgebenlines = (sum(1 for _ in f))
        with open('Text2.txt') as f:
            verkauftlines = (sum(1 for _ in f))
        with open('Text1.txt') as f:
            first_line_ausgegeben = f.readline()
        with open('Text2.txt') as f:
            first_line_verkauft = f.readline()
        def minus():
            with open('Text2.txt', 'rb') as fin:
                data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
            with open('Text2.txt', 'wb') as fout:
                fout.writelines(data[1:])
        try:
            Wert = int(first_line_ausgegeben) - int(first_line_verkauft)
            print(Wert)
            if ausgebenlines == 0 and verkauftlines == 0:
                ende()
            with open('Text1.txt') as f:
                first_line_ausgegeben = f.readline()
            with open('Text2.txt') as f:
                first_line_verkauft = f.readline()
            Gewinn.append(Wert)
            minus()
        except Exception :
            print('Fertig')
        if verkauftlines == 0:
            gewinn = sum(Gewinn)
            print('Fertig, Es ist noch so viel da: ' + str(gewinn))
            time.sleep(5)
    test()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Explanation:
Take all numbers from Text2, then add them all together, then substract with the number in Text1. Now my problem is, that isnt really working and it is really slow, but it needs to be fast, at the end Text2 will have probably 100 - 200 Lines and with that speed it would take 10 Minutes, could someone help me?
Thanks.
Edit:
The Text1 would look something like that:

```
[Line 1]: 500
```

Text2:

```
[Line 1]: 5
[Line 2]: 6
[Line 3]: 2
[Line 4]: 7
[Line 5]: 2
[Line 6]: 9
etc
```

And now it should take all numbers from Text2, add them, subtract them with the number from Text1 and then output that
(And i know the code isnt the best, im not really good in python)
Oh, and one more thing, there wont be something like [Line 1], it should just tell you guys what the Text1 & Text2 would look like

Comment: what does "at the end" mean? why is your code inside an infinite loop? what do you mean take all numbers from text2? What is your input, what should be your output? Your question needs more clarity

Comment: Why is the whole thing in a while loop, and why are there `sleep` calls?

Comment: Example `Text1` and `Text2` file and expected output will make it more clear as to what you want to acheive. And btw, your `time.sleep(3)` is what is making the program run for 10 mins... 200 times 3..

Comment: Alright so: At the end was said wrong, I mean that Text2 will have 100 - 200 Lines, I made it in an infinite Loop because I needed to see the Errors that were there (The Loop isn't needed) and there should be no input, it just should read Text2, add all numbers that are in there, then it maybe is something like 300, then it substract it with the Number that is in Text1, my first problem is, it isnt even working, the other problem is, even if it would work, this is really, really slow, do you need more information?

Comment: Is the file `Text2.txt` an input or output file? Because you first read it, then you overwrite it.

Comment: As I understand your explaination: 1) read all numbers in Text1 and add them 2) read all numbers in Text2 and add them 3) substract result of 2) from 1). is this right?

Comment: @SamDaniel Oh yes, but still, it isnt outputing the things it should. This is what Text1 would look like:
500
This is what Text2 would look like (Every number is in is own line)
5
6
9
2
etc

Comment: @Feodoran So it should read all of the lines, then it should add every number that was in there and subtract it with the number that is in Text2

Comment: @Feodoran No, it should read all Numbers in Text2, add them, then subtract it with the number (There will only be one number) in Text1

Comment: I would still suggest to post  example input files and expected output, so we dont take guesses

Comment: @SamDaniel I edited the post, maybe you understand now what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sum of all numbers in one file, you simply read all lines, convert to integer and sum up:

```
with open('Text2.txt') as f:
    numbers = map(int, f.readlines())
n2 = sum(numbers)
```

Now simply load the first number from the other file, and calculate the difference.

```
with open('Text1.txt') as f:
    n1 = int(f.readlines()[0])  # possible further numbers are ignored

diff = n2 - n1
print(diff)
```